# Ending of Venus in Fur movie

Tags: ending, venus-in-fur

What happened in *Venus in Fur*? Is the lady character the real goddess **Venus**?

Answer (score 1):

In the film, it appears this is intentionally left a mystery. To [quote Emmanuelle Seigner](http://m.huffpost.com/us/entry/emmanuelle-seigner-in-venus-in-furs_b_5517184.html), the actress who played Vanda and the wife of the director:

> We don’t know. Maybe she is from his mind. Like in Rosemary’s Baby, at the end you can think, maybe she dreamt all that. Or maybe she is a goddess, or an actress that wanted to teach the director a lesson. Who knows? I like that it is open and mysterious.

However, in [an interview with the playwright, David Ives](http://www.economist.com/blogs/prospero/2012/05/qa-david-ives), he seems to indicate that Vanda is a flesh-and-blood person.

> ...like the fact that Vanda [*the character*] is an army brat and Nina [*the actress*] really is an army brat.